# Scrape web data with Google sheets importhtml?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a task for a work tool that I need to import names and prices for hardware on our website. It is set up like a normal website so as an example Im going to use amazon for my question.

Basically for my question is could I use importhtml/xml and get just the name of said product like this "**RYOBI RY29550....**" And then the price "**6.80**" in separate columns?

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00QMKU89K/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_image_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00QMKU89K)

I have never used the import formulas before and have read a bit but am unsure how to set it up if possible. I know it's set up like
=Importhtml or xml("website", [need help here])

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Greetings. You want `IMPORTXML` ([Doc ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)). Syntax: `IMPORTXML(url, xpath_query)`. You already have the URL, you need to learn about `xpath_query`. Google suggests [w3chools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). Most browsers have a tool or add-on that will give the xpath; thses StackOverflow topics are also useful: {XPath for elements using Chrome?}(https://stackoverflow.com/q/39864280/1330560) and [How to handle double quotes in xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33271376/1330560).

Comment: FWIW, you should be able to extract this xpath if you want to display the price from your Amazon link: `//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]`.

Comment: Brad, one last thing... You said _I have never used the import formulas before and have read a bit but am unsure how to set it up_. My best advice is: just give it a go. The documentation is helpful, and there is no shortage of examples on StackOverflow and Webapps. You have to start somewhere.

Comment: I really appreciate the links and help! I'm definitely going to look through and have to learn a bit more about Xpaths!

Comment: Excellent. BTW, the reason I included the link to "How to handle double quotes in xpath" is because the price xpath has double quotes AND when I tested it... well, it didn't work. But that link tells to how to fix it. Hint: change the double quotes to single quotes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the info! I really appreciate it